# Multi-agent vs multi-robot systems

Tags: multi-agent

I'm building a multi-agent system, and I heard about multi-robot systems.
Can anyone explain the differences between multi-agent and multi-robot systems, and when to use one or the other?

Answer (score 2):

In general - robots refer to real or simulated mechanical systems, whereas an agent could be a physical or non-physical entity like a chatbot program or neural net.

Comment: Thank you @Ari Onasafari. So a robot is a physical agent.